# TransferManager upload doesn't actually upload file

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to follow the tutorial for uploading a file to S3 from from the Android SDK, as outlined [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html#upload-an-object). After successfully verifying that I was able to create a CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider, I tried to execute an upload from my device to an S3 bucket I already set up. I have the following code to attempt this:

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                            context, identityProvider, null, {autARN});
Log.d("LogTag", "my ID is " + credentialsProvider.getIdentityId()); //shows me the IdentityId; credentialsProvider is valid
TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(credentialsProvider);
File file = new File("/storage/sdcard0/Download");
Upload upload = transferManager.upload({Bucket Name}, "test.txt", file);
while (upload.isDone() == false) {
    System.out.println(upload.getProgress().getPercentTransferred() + "%");
}
```

The while loop shows me that 0% of my file has been uploaded, and indeed my file does not show up as expected in the target bucket. Anyone have any clue why the file isn't being uploaded as intended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is probably an error of some sort, can you turn on request logging and see if you see any response errors in the logs?

adb shell setprop log.tag.com.amazonaws.request DEBUG

and in your code:

java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.amazonaws.request").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);

One thing to double check is that you setup your S3 bucket permissions correctly: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html#set-permissions-on-the-bucket

Comment: thanks for the answer. the logging revealed the error which was that I set the unauthenticated arn to null in the credentials provider. i thought that was ok since i didn't enable unauthenticated users. i changed that and it worked. what's weird is that afterwards, i went back and retried it again with the null value and now that's working also! pretty confused by all of this, but at least it's working now, so thank you